# Stock Symbols: ETFs vs Real Companies

Tags: equities, algorithmic-trading, etf

I built a trading strategy that is based on a pool of all the symbols available on NYSE, Nasdaq, and AMEX.

I don't like the idea of trading symbols that are ETFs. For example, the symbol TVIX, which is some velocity shares 2x leveraged bull****, is not something that I want to trade.

Is there a list maintained somewhere of the symbols on these exchanges, and which ones represent ETFs or other funds? I've looked all over the place and can't seem to find anything that differentiates symbols in this way.

Comment: What database are you using to find your NYSE/NASDAQ/Amex stock symbols? In CRSP for example ordinary companes have Share Code 10 or 11, while ETFs have Share Code 70 or 71.

Comment: I use the data available is CSV form from Nasdaq.com at `http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange={exchange}&render=download` where the `exchange` parameter can equal `nyse`, `nasdaq`, or `amex`. Is the CRSP accessible for free?

Comment: Unfortunately CRSP is free only for professors and students at major universities, otherwise very expensive. There are other choices, though.

Comment: What is your operating environment?  Which platform(s) do you use?

Comment: My trading strategy is written in java. My primary data source is quandl, but as mentioned above, I get basic information about symbols from nasdaq.com. Really not looking to pay for this data, as it seems super simple.

Comment: It all seems simple until you dig deeper.  Do you want standard Operating/Holding companies, Public Limited Partnerships, Royalty Trusts, Investment Companies, Closed End Funds, Business Development Companies, Special Purpose Companies, Liquidation Trusts, Litigation Trusts, Special Purpose Acquisition Companies.  How do you handle multiple classes of shares?  What about voting/non-voting rights? How about ADRs for foreign companies?  How do you handle ADRs against Preferreds?  There are many types too that you need to ignore - Debt, Hybrid, Rights, Warrants, certain Units.   It is not simple.

Comment: I understand, but the complexity you're describing is kinda getting away from the question, which is essentially asking for a company type classification for symbols. Just seems absurd that there is not a publicly available source defining basic characteristics of securities that are available for public trading and regulated by the gov.

Comment: There is an ISO specification for security types (ISO 10962 - Classification of Financial Instruments) - it's just that few companies use it (only the large institutional data providers do) and their usage is often riddled with errors.  We use multiple sources for our own classification scheme, look for discrepancies between schemes and frequently manually override them.  It's a big job.  The data that comes from the exchanges is too simplistic.  Most of our users prefer to use index constituents where only certain types of securities are included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for at Nasdaq.com. This information wasn't available months ago when I initially built my trading strategy. Basically Nasdaq.com provides a CSV file of all symbols that are ETFs. And its free.

http://www.nasdaq.com/investing/etfs/etf-finder-results.aspx?download=Yes

Answer (score 0):

I use http://etfdb.com/etfs/ the ETF Database.  It gives a large amount of data including:

- a rating of the ETF,
- Alternatives,
- Holdings, Expenses & Fees,
- Performance,
- Charts,
- Valuation,
- Dividend,
- Technicals,
- Fact Sheet,
- Read Next, and more. 
  You can go through ETFs on this website by category.  Also after initial worked of creating a "master list" that you want to follow, you should be able create software for getting data from this site...

You can also download a file the screening results on the website -- see "use our ETF sceener".  There it also allows you to pick 1) types of ETFs of interest (e.g. bonds, commodities, equities, etc) 2) Size and type of companies can be specified. 3) specify the "attributes " (e.g. commission free, leveraged, inverse, etc).  You just have sign up to download a .csv file the results of your screening and that is free!

Comment: is there any way of getting the data via an URL request?

Comment: After eliminating the ETFs, you will need to eliminate the REITs, the MLPs, the ADRs, the Certificates of Participation and so on. Seems like there must be a better way to come up with a list of 'real US companies'.

Comment: Agreed @AlexC. My best approach at this point is to use regular on the name field on the data provided by nasdaq at `http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download` to filter out companies that fit the description of ETF/Fund/etc. After sifting through the ~6,000 companies that compose NYSE, Nasdaq, and Amex, I came up with ~15 phrases that generally characterize these funds. Its proven reasonably accurate so far.

Comment: What are your 15 phrases?  What degree of accuracy do you require?

Comment: You can do the selection process directly from the http://etfdb.com/etfs/ the ETF Database, avoiding the extra work.

Comment: There is drop down on the http://etfdb.com/etfs/  site that lets select select different categories (e.g Bond/Fixed Income, Commodity, Currency, etc.).  Then within categories there are "more detailed" selections (e.g with Bond/Fixed Income you have Corporate Bonds, Emerging Market Bonds, etc).  If that's to much work for you, there is also the ETFdb ETF Screener on the site.